# Add object with same key in vuejs

Tags: object, vue.js, addition

I'm using vuejs and laravel.
In component, i have:

```
data(): {
   return {
     data: []
   }
}
```

After fetching, i have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrBEu.png).
I want to load more data if user scroll, so i have to add new object into data.

I tried **Object.assign**, **push**... but the properties had be overwritten.
I also loop the data and add new object but not work either...

I want something like:

```
obj1 = {0: value1, 1: value2};
obj2 = {0: value3, 1: value4};
=> obj = {0: value1, 1: value2, 3: value3, 4: value4};
```

Any idea? Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the values from the object using `Object.values()`, then join both of the values using `array#concat` then using `Object.assign()` create your object.

```js
const obj1 = {0: 'value1', 1: 'value2'},
      obj2 = {0: 'value3', 1: 'value4'},
      result = Object.assign({}, Object.values(obj1).concat( Object.values(obj2)));
console.log(result);
```

You can also use `array#reduce` instead of `Object.assign`.

```js
const obj1 = {0: 'value1', 1: 'value2'},
      obj2 = {0: 'value3', 1: 'value4'},
      result = Object.values(obj1).concat( Object.values(obj2)).reduce((r,v,i) => (r[i] = v, r), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: work like a charm! 
Tks so much, you saved my day <3

Answer (score 0):

```
data:function(){
   return {
     data: []
   }
}
```

Now you can add element either by

```
this.data.push(object);
```

or You can concat another array like this -

```
this.data = this.data.concat(anotherArray);
```

After Updating the question -

```
/* For the case in question, you would do: */
Object.assign(obj1, obj2);

/** There's no limit to the number of objects you can merge.
 *  All objects get merged into the first object. 
 *  Only the object in the first argument is mutated and returned.
 *  Later properties overwrite earlier properties with the same name. */

let obj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2, obj3, etc);
```

Comment: Tks, i tried but that not the answer i need.
I edited my question, please take a look!